# MySQL connection works in PHP but not ASP

Tags: php, mysql, database, asp-classic, connection

I have to do a MySQL-Database connection to a remote server using ASP. When I use normal PHP everything is fine. If I use following ASP code

```
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;" & _  
           "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
           "Server=mysqlsvr.domain.com;" & _
           "Database=database1;" & _
           "Uid=username;" & _
           "Pwd=password"
```

I always get the error that the database is not reachable or permission denied... but with PHP everything works fine?! Do you know where the problem is?

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Are ASP and PHP on the same server?

Comment: if the db is MySQL why are you using Driver={SQL Server};?

Answer (score 1):

connection string is wrong. Try:

```
"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=mysqlsvr.domain.com; DATABASE=database1; UID=username;PASSWORD=password;"
```

You need Mysql ODBC driver installed

Answer (score 0):

Connect without a DSN

**'define the connection string, specify database driver**

```
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=Your_Mysql_DB; " &_ "UID=mysql_username;PASSWORD=mysql_password; OPTION=3"
```

**'create an instance of the ADO connection and recordset objects**

```
 Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Connection with DSN

**'create an instance of the ADO connection and recordset objects**

```
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

**'open the connection to the database**

```
Connection.Open "DSN=dsn_name"
```

**'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records**

```
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
```